# How to have new Chrome bookmarks appear at the top of the list

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks

I'm using Chrome. When adding a new bookmark to a folder (or to bookmarks bar), it should appear at the top of the list, not the bottom (because, being newer, it is more likely to be more relevant to what I'm doing than what was bookmarked a year ago).

Are there any extensions that fix this issue?

Comment: Why would they even have it as the default to append to the bottom?  Nice post!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this automatically without an extension.  I'm getting this information from the [Google Support Fourm](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=67427bbffd4f4aff&hl=en).

If you want an extension, use [BoogleMarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hojigclpigghnkdhhkhgjobmoghdecae)

Comment: What a fail this is on chrome's part.  It should be the default behavior, but given that it's not it should at least be a native setting

Comment: BoogleMarks does not seem to exist. Any other suggestions?