# Add New Chrome Bookmark Folders at the Top?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

When I create a new bookmark folder in Chrome, it adds it to the bottom of my bookmarks list. I.e. if I have the following bookmark list

- folder1
- folder2
- someBookmark
- someOtherBookmark

If I create folder3, it will add it to the bottom of the list

- folder1
- folder2
- someBookmark
- someOtherBookmark
- **folder3**

Is it possible to add new folders to the top of the list? I.e.

- **folder3**
- folder1
- folder2
- someBookmark
- someOtherBookmark

Answer (score 2):

The chrome extension [Bookmarks Reorderer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-reorderer/dojjmigcfgjcjakkdhmnkcjajbjcjnja/) can do that

[image: picture of the chrome web store]

Comment: Thanks a lot, my search is complete! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This extension does not specifically apply to folders, as requested. The reordering settings affect ALL bookmarks and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `chrome://bookmarks/` by pasting the URL into the address box

You can manually drag and drop the folders in whatever position you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you configure it to do this automatically without dragging and dropping?

Comment: looks like this feature was requested here:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/15865721?hl=en

Comment: Similar question:

https://superuser.com/questions/371486/how-to-have-new-chrome-bookmarks-appear-at-the-top-of-the-list